# Magento 2:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, grid, query, join

I have added a new column in customer grid using the following:

**app/code/Company/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!--Custom Added to display in customer grid-->
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection"
            type="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection2" />
    <virtualType name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection2" type="Company\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\CustomerDataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">customer_grid_flat</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <!--Custom Added to display in customer grid End-->
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/CustomerDataProvider.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Company\Module\Ui\Component\Listing;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class CustomerDataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
   protected function _initSelect()
   {
      parent::_initSelect();
      $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('custom_table')],
        'main_table.entity_id = secondTable.customer_id',
        ['customer_permissions']
      );
      return $this;
  }
}
```

**app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
 <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <column name="customer_permissions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">  
                    <item name="notapproved" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disapproved</item>
                    </item>  
                     <item name="approved" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Approved</item>
                    </item>
            </item>   
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Approved</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">265</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
  </columns>
</listing>
```

The custom column is added.

But while deleting the customer using mass action, I'm getting an error as:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id` FROM `customer_grid_flat` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `custom_table` AS `secondTable` ON main_table.entity_id = secondTable.customer_id WHERE (`entity_id` IN('6'))

This is the `custom_table` structure:

[image: custom_table structure]

The column name in table `custom_table` is `entity_id`. Also the column name in table `customer_grid_flat` is `entity_id`.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Can you post your delete Action here ? and model function too, if any.

Comment: I am getting the error while deleting the customers from grid using mass action. Hence the delete action is default customer delete mass action.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
protected function _initSelect()  {

  $this->addFilterToMap('entity_id', 'main_table.entity_id');
  parent::_initSelect();
  $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('custom_table')],
    'main_table.entity_id = secondTable.customer_id',
    ['customer_permissions']
  );
  return $this; 

 }
```

In your `app/code/Company/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/CustomerDataProvider.php` file , update the `_initSelect()` function as above and try.

Comment: it's work fine.tks u!